# User suggested great corrective edit to my answer, but the edit was rejected. What can I do to approve it?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, code, rejected-edits

A nice user suggested [a good corrective edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/288019) to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810422/changing-the-image-in-facebook-post-to-wall-page-ios/10811503#10811503). The edit, though very good and desirable, was rejected. I do not understand the reasons, and I did not find a way to contact those people who rejected it. What can I do to re-approve the edit?

Comment: could you not just edit the answer yourself? You should be able to as it is your answer.

Comment: Probably was rejected since it modified the code. It's really better if only the post owner modifies the code.

Comment: Yeah, it is easy to do the edit on my own. I will. I just wanted to avoid discouraging the user who pointed at the mistake. It was probably his first attempt on StackOverflow...

Comment: Related on Meta Server Fault: [I accidentally rejected a suggested edit that should have been approved. What do I do now?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5299/i-accidentally-rejected-a-suggested-edit-that-should-have-been-approved-what-do)

Answer (score 5):

Starting today, this is possible. See: [Could authors overturn recent community review decisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028)