# Invited to review an edit on my post but I don't have the privilege

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review, etiquette, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [User suggested great corrective edit to my answer, but the edit was rejected. What can I do to approve it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135967/user-suggested-great-corrective-edit-to-my-answer-but-the-edit-was-rejected-wh)

I've been invited (for the first time) to review an edit someone made to my post on SO, but I've only got 1609 rep and the buttons to accept etc aren't showing, even though the two versions are displayed side by side. It's a good edit correcting a silly mistake. Two reviewers who don't frequent our tag rejected it, but the reviewer who does correctly accepted it. I'd like to accept it, but don't think I can. Should I just edit my post myself and thank the edit suggester in a comment? (I thought it might be a browser bug, but two different ones don't show me any buttons.)

Comment: Not quite - I was asking why SO was asking me to review and not letting me. This answer clears up my misunderstanding that reviewing depended on reputation.

Comment: Not at all, reputation had nothing to do with it. You can *always* review suggested edits on your own posts, no matter what your reputation is. The real issue was you wanted to approve an edit which was already rejected, which that question covers perfectly.

Comment: At the time I thought there might be some bug or fault, and _did not know_ I could review edits on my own posts. The other Q was of no help to me because I didn't realise it had been rejected. Although the _solution_ to both problems is the same, and the required _outcome_ is the same, the perceived _problem_ was totally different. The point of leaving questions unclosed is to help future users who have the same lack of knowledge. I knew how I could reinstate but didn't understand it was rejected. The other question asks how to reinstate if you know it's rejected. Different lack of knowledge.

Comment: Then you're looking for [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: No I knew that & I don't need any more help now - I accepted the answer below, but I think other people may be in my problem later because their first ever review might be rejected before they read it, and they won't find your other answer, because they don't know that's their problem! I tried these searches and more I've forgotten: review my post, review own post, review priviledges. I didn't find the Q you answered because it's not about review malfunction (my perceived problem). I found a Q about the layout of review with a screenshot, that's how I knew the buttons were missing.

Comment: That's the point of closing. The question won't be deleted, and will still be completely searchable for users who think the same as you, but merely link to other questions which already answer the real problem behind what you're experiencing.

Comment: Did not know that, thanks. Meta is different. Note to self: Remember that meta is different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you don't see an option to accept is because the edit has already been rejected by two reviewers. It only takes 2 votes, there is no option to repeal that vote, I'm afraid.

Fix the post yourself (thanking the Good Samaritan in a comment perhaps). If you really feel generous, find a good answer or question by that editor and give it an upvote. That'll more than repay the missed +2 reputation.

Comment: I don't condone "finding a post of theirs and upvotng it." This screws the post's score in favor when in fact the person may not even know the accuracy of the post in question. It could be an absolutely terrible question/answer and they're getting an upvote for it from something completely unrelated. If you have the time to actually review one of their posts, feel free to upvote it. But don't just click in, upvote, and click out. That is **never** acceptable.

Comment: I would certainly never do that, no. SO is about good answers to good questions. Martijn suggested I find a _good_ answer or question, so I had a nosey and read some answers in my area of expertise. When I came across one which I considered undervalued by the community, with some strong and perceptive advice not contained in the accepted answer, I upvoted it - I would have done this anyway if I'd read there.

Comment: I hesitate to say this, because I've learned that suggesting changing on the basis of my experience as a relative newcomer is very frowned upon here at meta, but it seems it would be clearer if the review screen said explicitly that review was closed because the edit had been rejected by two reviewers, rather than simply hiding the buttons. I'll completely buy the answer that this happens to you only once and that my question here documents the situation, so actually I officially don't suggest that. Thinking aloud.

Comment: Look again at the [suggested edit in question](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/650738). At the top it says, in red, "Rejected *relative time* ago:" followed by the review decisions.

Comment: <facepalm> so sorry folks. Note to self: Read the screen. Read all the screen. Read the screen carefully. Think about what it says on the screen. Thanks meta people for being so tolerant, helpful and patient with me on this one.