# Do authors see suggested edits which were rejected by the community?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

There is a [questions here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions) that seem to indicate that the authors of a post see suggested edits, even if the edits have already been rejected by the community.

But then I also saw a comment today that indicates that the OP did not see the actual proposed edit: "someone (...) tried to edit the post twice today, and the edits were apparently NOT approved (as the post isn't edited)".

So, what does an author see if an edit to his post is proposed and rejected before he re-visits the site?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, as an author you see that an edit was suggested on your post, whether it is rejected or accepted, or still pending.

You are sent a notification the moment the suggested edit is proposed, and that notification remains active and available even when the suggested edit was rejected.

> [image: Suggested edit link]

There are two links in the notification: the `review it` text links to the suggested edit itself, the other link goes directly to the post.

Comment: @oberlies: yes, the notification includes a link to that page.

Comment: Took the liberty to add relevant screenshot. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd gets the +1 on his comment cause he has free hand circles in his content. You really missed the mark on this one Martijn. :-)

Comment: @ryan: I am still waiting for someone to *suggest* edits for my posts, rather than just edit them outright! :-P

Comment: Duh, there is one in my notification history... updated with a smaller shot, more detailed circle.

Comment: hmmm, well I can't sub the +1 from Sha so I guess I'll just have to give you a +1 as well.

Comment: @ryan: Why, thank you! You are most graceful!

Comment: @ryan we can undo comment upvote, did you try?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you can only do it in the grace period much like undoing your vote on a question. otherwise it doesn't give you the option.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: This very post had an edit suggestion, just now. I reviewed the suggested edit by clicking on the notification. It is *still there* in my notifications box. It does not disappear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters D'oh, retracting my last comment. I was looking in the `inbox` tab, not the `notifications` tab. This had been really annoying me; I'm glad I was just confused. Thanks for clearing this up.