# Are suggested edits ever deleted?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have recently made an edit that probably was only rejected, because the reviewer was afraid to check if the added content was correct or not (not much was added, see https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/813430), combined with the fact that the post came from a high-rep user.

How do I assume that? Supposedly, my edit changed the intent of the post, which is a little far fetched when all the edit does apart from fixing typos, a minor error and changing one sentence to avoid repition of the word 'hence', is fill a small gap - in a post that is pretty detailed and *very much written in a way not to leave gaps* (I'm talking about a mathematical proof).

So, what I did was ask the author if he would include my rejected edit, using the comment. It might however be possible that he won't respond, since he hasn't been active for a year or so.
Hence, I'm wondering if the link to the suggested edit in the comment will be there as long as SE is up, or if it will be deleted some time soon, so that the information pertaining to the edit remains available *at least somewhere*.

Comment: suggested edits and their review outcome are kept in the database forever.

Comment: Since I'm a little pedantic... the edit being in the database is not the same as it being accessible through the above link. So, will the link also always refer to the edit in the database?

Comment: Here you can see all past rejections of suggested edits on math.se: http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/671680

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of some unusual database manipulation, suggested edits are never deleted; if the author ever returns, they'll be able to view your edit.

Heck, if no subsequent edits are made to the post, the author can even [overturn the rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028) and cause your rejected edit to be applied, should they wish to do so.

Comment: ... and does that also mean that the link will 'always' be referring to the undeleted entry's contents (see my own comment reply in the question)?

Comment: Yes, the link should remain stable.

Comment: what about hiding suggested edit spam? This feature was mentioned as built in March '17 section of [monthly features overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291032/165773), I wonder if these are just blocked from displaying or deleted

Comment: The former, @gnat.