# Empty review guidance banner visible when queue is empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design

When a review queue is empty, the 'guidance' banner stays visible, though it has no content.

I'm pretty sure this banner wasn't visible yesterday, so it's a recent <s>change</s> bug.

[image]

Comment: Poked a dev about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A story in four not uniformly taken screenshots!

[image: are we good for a prod build?]
[image: maybe!]
[image: uh oh]
[image: the wheel knows all]

This was a side-effect of [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298526). No other queues have guidance at this point. Fix is rolling out now.

Comment: I would love to see user The Wheel of Blame in the Tavern..... :D