# Should I be offered reject button on the tag-wiki I wrote myself?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Recently I suggested edit to [tag-wiki on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/85567) (I am [below 20k](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/trusted-user) on that site.) The suggested edit was approved. When I looked at the edit suggestion again, I noticed that I am offered reject button together with this explanatory text (screenshot below):

> This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required.
>
> If you disagree with this edit being approved, you can return your post to its previous state using the Reject button below.

This does not seem to be specific to one site, I found the same behavior [on sports.SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11692) (screenshot below).

If I understand this correctly, the system consider me as the owner of the post, since I created the tag-wiki. And then, since a suggested edit was made to my post, the system offers me a possibility to reject it. (IIRC the post owner has the final say on suggested edit and they can vote to approve or reject suggested edit of their own post, regardless of their reputation.)

However, it seems to me a bit illogical that I have a possibility to reject my own suggested edit. I think it would be better to remove this option. (I.e., you should not be able to vote on a suggested edit on your post if it is your own suggested edit.)

---

Screenshot from MathOverflow:

[image: screenshot]

Screenshot from Sports:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 90% sure this is a bug caused by [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298526/164356) #TheWheelOfBlame

Comment: @Floern no, that's just a textual guidance that was added, nothing changed in the logic.

Comment: Pretty sure this will fail with error, but indeed that option shouldn't be there in this case.

Comment: @Shadow ah you're right, focused too much on the guidance

Comment: @Floern no problem, and for the record this is the source of the bug here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that this button "hurts" even if that edit suggestion came from the owner himself/herself. That also allows you to revert that suggestion if someone approved or rejected your edit and applied their own edit to it ("improve edit" and "reject and edit") .

Comment: Hmm no you shouldn't. That button should really only appear for moderators on tag wikis.

Comment: The worst thing would be if you have a rejected edit suggestion and you have the possibility to override the rejection and approve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely something we just didn't consider when implementing this feature. We had tag wikis in the back of our minds as "eh we're not really sure how well this will play with them" but didn't consider the user permissions aspect.

That said, this feature introduces a serious loophole in that the "owner" of a tag wiki can unilaterally approve all of their own edits after-the-fact if the community opts to reject them. So I poked Oded to tweak the permissions there to only ever show those options to moderators on tag wikis and their excerpts. The fix will be live at the next build.