# Allow rollbacks for tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, tag-wiki, rollbacks

So, on Myth.SE, there were some interesting tag wiki suggested edits, using content directly copied from Wikipedia. Stack Exchange does not appreciate that.

So some of our newer users approved it, as our review team is not that great right now. And now were stuck with 5 <s>[t](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tags/norse/info)[a](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tags/mythical-creatures/info)[g](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tags/greek/info) [wik](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tags/hindu/info)[is](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tags/egyptian/info)</s> Wikipedia excerpts.

So... Please?

Comment: Sweet, the Reject-the-edit-after-review-is-complete feature *does* work on tag wikis. That's so convenient. :)

Comment: @animuson Wait, after??? How

Comment: [See here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028)

Comment: Doesn't this already exist?

Comment: I thought so too. Until...

Answer (score 1):

I am to blame for those tag wikis.

I didn't know that we shouldn't use Wikipedia for writing tag wikis. I only felt that those tags didn't have a big enough tag wiki so I thought of using Wikipedia, since Wikipedia is a free source of knowledge.

My only motive was to get good info onto the tag wiki page. Usually, for answers and all, I wouldn't copy anything from Wikipedia, and I try to keep it original. However, since the tag wikis need to have thorough information on that topic, Wikipedia was a good place to get that information from.

I was a little new to Mythology SE, and I hope to contribute more over there. I hope to hear a few tips about writing tag wikis, since that's one of the few ways I can help the site.

Comment: Tag wikis are not about thorough information on a topic. They are about information on *how to use the tag*.

Comment: Yea, I tried to ping you in chat to inform you, but you never entered it, so you didn't get pinged :P, but yea, don't do it next time.