# Suspended users can still use the "suggested edit review override" tool

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, account-suspension, edit-override

The new tool [allowing the OP of a post to override community review on suggested edits to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/278659) **doesn't take account of the fact that said OP may be suspended**! Or rather, it does but only partially so: a suspended OP can press the "Reject" button on an edit that's already been approved, and this will show up both on the review item and in their activity history, but the edit doesn't actually get rolled back. This is what happened [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/65462), for example.

Technically this doesn't actually have any effect on the site - presumably the existing blocks preventing suspended users from making edits kick in after the review has been done - but it's still worrying that users are able to perform any activity on the site while suspended. Especially since one of the reasons for suspension is self-vandalism of one's own posts, and once a user is suspended there's nothing *more* that can be done to them to prevent them performing activities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is fixed.

You were right on the money with this.  There was no suspension check validating whether or not the user could override, so the button showed up, and clicking it caused the approval/rejection to happen, followed by an exception when trying to edit with a suspended user.

It was a one-line fix to suppress the button and prevent validation.