# Reverted edit has funny accounting for <2k Copy Editor

Tags: bug, reputation, suggested-edits

The end of my reputation listing on SuperUser says:

```
earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits
```

But I only have 499 +2's in the reputation listing. And since **499 * 2 != 1000**, something is a bit odd here.

---

I am going to guess that this somehow tied up in the fact that I am <2k but have over 500 edits and yesterday saw this:

[image]

Which corresponds with this:

[image]

Interestingly neither of these appears in my reputation detail:

---

```
-- 2017-03-20 rep 0
```

---

```
 2   1200093 (10)
-- 2017-07-31 rep +10   = 1680      
-- 2017-08-02 rep 0     = 1680      
-- 2017-08-24 rep 0     = 1680
```

So the reputation details claims 1000 points awarded, but I have only been awarded 998. Is this expected behavior, or is this a bug?

**Update after duplicate link:**

While the [linked duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions) certainly does explain what the *-2 reverted* means, it does not address why the rep output claims that I have been awarded 1000 points for editing, when in fact it looks like I have only been awarded 998.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could authors overturn recent community review decisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions)

Comment: @gnat: While that does answer it implicitly, it's not a dupe by any means. It's a good reference, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Moderators and Post Owners can override an approved edit which causes the person who suggested the edit to lose the 2 rep they gained as a result of edit approval.

Did you check [the revision of that post](https://superuser.com/revisions/1186973/3)?

The Post Owner over-rode your approved edit. He rolled it back to revision 1.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not address: *why does the rep detail indicate 1000 points given, but only 998 points are actually given.*

Comment: 1000 points given but a -2 is then taken away