# Minor problems with overriding suggested edit reviews

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, moderators, edit-override

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/295232), authors and ♦ moderators are now able to override reviews of suggested edits. I was curious if this would work for [edits I suggested myself](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/196992) (from before the time I was a moderator).

[It turns out it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oacfb.gif) Maybe that's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but it still feels strange to 'give' myself 2 reputation (you can see the reputation change from 1809 to 1811 in the top bar). Therefore, I decided to <kbd>Reject</kbd> the edit again. This also worked, in spite of this statement in Shog9's post:

> - A suggested edit can only be overridden *once*.

If I now try to approve the edit again, it fails, but the error message is empty:

[image: screenshot of suggested edit review item]