# Do not allow the author or a moderator to override an edit if it results in blocked tags being applied

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, blocked-tags, untagged-questions, edit-override

Due to a [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028), a user was allowed to [override](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/86200/revisions) an approved edit, which resulted in their question getting tagged with the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag.  That should not be allowed, given that no question should be untagged (unless it was migrated from another site or had all of its tags burninated), and the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is prevented from normally being applied as it is blocked network-wide.

Therefore, that feature should check if overriding a suggested edit will cause the question to use blocked tags, and if so, it should reject the override attempt.

Alternatively, in this situation the rollback could only revert the content of the post and not the tags.

Comment: [Untagged](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a tag that was added on DIY.se and is now a normal tag (used in burnination requests IIRC). That question has never been in an "untagged" state, it was just in a state with a tag that carried that name. It is unclear how this feature request should distinguish legit rollbacks compared to rollbacks you deem unwanted.

Comment: Broadened your request. The [tag:untagged] tag is blacklisted, and so this request applies to any overriding where a blacklisted tag would be applied.

Answer (score 8):

With the understanding that we're talking about an edge case of an edge case... this request clearly has good intentions, but it seems like it could lead to mild abuse.

The reason for overriding an edit is to undo changes; changes which are inadvertently harmful or outright malicious. Disallowing such overrides in some cases would make bad content last longer on the sites. Yes, the post could still be re-edited instead of rolled back, but that's more work, and maybe more importantly, a greater mental barrier than clicking one link.

Maybe the solution here is to take this sub-case of overrides and send them to an editor window, populated with the rolled-back title/body and an empty tag field, which would require the addition of valid tags before submission can proceed?