# How many suggested edits have been overturned and by whom?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, statistics, edit-override

For more than a year and half, [authors and moderators have been able to override suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/213575). Well, what better excuse than being near new years' to get some data. So, how many times have the decisions of reviewers been  overturned in the entire network and by whom?

- Number of suggested edits
- Number of votes from review for reject
- Number of votes from review for approve
- Number of votes by authors to approve a rejected
- Number of votes by authors to reject a approved
- Number of votes by moderators to approve a rejected
- Number of votes by moderators to reject a approved

Answer (score 12):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can answer most of this; note that it does not make a distinction between authors and moderators overriding a review outcome, and it does not contain the UserId of the reviewers. When an approval is overridden, that generates a rollback which appears in the PostHistory table, so we can check whether the author initiated that or not; that trick doesn't work for rejections which are overridden.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1583838/statistics-on-overridden-suggested-edits?From=2017-04-22&Until=2022-12-31) is an attempt to gather some statistics. For Stack Overflow, since that feature was rolled out, almost 2 million edits have been suggested, and about 1.6% of those decisions get reverted:

| Category | Total | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 1927641 | 100 |
| (Initially) rejected | 438306 | 22.74 |
| (Initially) approved | 1489335 | 77.26 |
| Rejected, then approved | 18630 | 0.97 |
| Approved, then rejected by author | 11402 | 0.59 |
| Approved, then rejected by moderator | 1689 | 0.09 |

(I'm aware that the feature enabled even older suggested edit reviews to be overridden, but since it only works if no further edits were made, I think it's not useful to include older suggested edits in the statistics. But the query supports it.)

Happy [King's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koningsdag) and don't forget to wear something orange!

Comment: Re *"wear something orange"*: That has a different connotation on a certain island.