# Improve wording of banner shown after reviewing a suggested edit on one of your own posts

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, wording

If you've reviewed a suggested edit on one of your own posts, you get a special banner since [this feature request was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178340/295232) (emphasis mine):

> You *voted* on this suggested edit to your post as noted below. No further action is required.

I know suggested edit reviews are stored as *votes* in the database, but that's not how users think about them (unless I have a very skewed point of view); we think of them as *reviews*. Can this banner message be changed something like this?

> You reviewed this suggested edit to your post as noted below. No further action is required.

---

[image: screenshot of current banner message]